# How to complete the whole list with Vim?

Tags: vim

I have a list of products to place on a rails seed and I would like to instead of put brackets one by one on the list with a command place the brackets on the whole list?

for example:

```
 1. Dakine 
 2. Dale of Norway
 3. Dan Post


 1. ["Dakine"],    
 2. ["Dale of Norway"],
 3. ["Dan Post"],
```

I searched on the help but did not find any about. Thanks.

Comment: Please ask one question per thread. Right now you're asking two. Pick either Vim or Atom or start two separate questions. I changed it to Vim for now because that has two answers.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker he ended up choosing the Atom solution though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Atom you can enable the find to use Regex in the search(there is a button next to the search field)
Then you can search for something like `(^.*$)` to get every line separated by groups and in the Replace field you use `["$1"],`. The `$1` represents the value matched by the Regex.
Then just do a Replace All and remove the last comma in your list if needed.

Comment: yes i will use the Atom, seems more simple. thank you @Doguita

Answer (score 1):

You can record a macro in Vim and repeat that.

If you are on number 1, you can do following:

> qqf a["Esc$a"],Esc0jq

Explanation:

`qq`: Start recording macro in register q

`f`: Go to first space character

`a`: : Insert after (the space character from above)

`\["`: Insert those characters

`Esc`: Back to normal mode

`$`: Go to end of line

`a`: Insert after (end of line)

`"],`: Insert the characters

`Esc`: Back to normal mode

`0`: Jump to start of line

`j`: Go down one line

If you have 100 such lines, you can do `100@q` to achieve your result.

Answer (score 1):

With vim substitute command:

```
:%s/.*/["&"]/
```

If you don't want to operate on all lines, then select the ones you want to transform or note the related line numbers, and then type `:s/.....` without the `%`. You'll see actually `:'<,'>s` this range represent the visually selected lines, and vim adds it automatically in visual mode.